# jQuery horizontal scrolling of text on mouseover to stop at the end of content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KpuyT/3/ However, I do not want the div to scroll infinitely - rather I would want the scroll to stop as soon as the text reaches its end and then on mouse-out to reset it back to its original position. I tried the following:

```
$(function(){
    var scroll_text,
        do_scroll = false;

    $('div.container').hover(
        function () {
            var $elmt = $(this);
            if ($elmt.find('div.title-holder a').width() > 130) {
                scroll_text = setInterval(function(){scrollText($elmt);}, 30);
                do_scroll = true;
            }
        },
        function () {
            if (do_scroll) {
                clearInterval(scroll_text);
                $(this).find('div.title-holder a').css({
                    left: 0
                });
            }
        },
        function (){
            $('div.container').scroll( function() {
                if ( $('div.container').scrollLeft() == ($('div.title-holder a').width() - $('div.container').width())) {
                    do_scroll = false;
                }
            });
        }
    );

    var scrollText = function($elmt){
        var left = $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').position().left - 1;
        left = -left > $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').width() ? $elmt.find('div.title-holder').width() : left;
        $elmt.find('div.title-holder a').css({
            left: left
        });
    };
});
```

But it does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could solve, based on the fiddle posted:

```
//move

$('div.container').hover(function(){
var $elmt = $(this);
$elmt.find('div.title-holder a').animate({
    left: '-'+ ($elmt.find('div.title-holder a').width() - $('.container').width())
  }, 5000);    
});

//and return to 0

$('div.container').mouseleave(function(){
var $elmt = $(this);
$elmt.find('div.title-holder a').animate({
    left: 0
  }, 5000);    
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LRTEJ/)

Comment: Thanks. That's how I wanted it.